# casting or data type conversion of primitive values

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

a) If I write something like this in java

```
short a = 15
short b = 3;
short c = a * b;//will not compile

I know it will not compile because short values are automatically
promoted to int with the resulting value of type int so this will compile:

int d=a*b ; //compile
```

B)If I do a multiplication of long numbers such as:

```
long a=15;
long b=3;
long c=a*b;//will compile
int d=a*b;//will not compile
```

I assume that long values do not get promoted to int because 
int is smaller,but also when I write

long a=15;

Java would have interpreted the literal as an int because there is no 'l' with 15 in assignment,if java had interpreted it as int why can't it multiply interpreting it as of int data types

```
int d=a*b;
```

Why should this give an error?

Does java not take into consideration the int value in case of any arithmetic operation of long variables ?

Why java allows long a=15; interpreting it as int when I can't do any operation on it as int .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that java converts upwards but not downward. It will convert to something bigger by adding space but by reducing space you might have loss of data therefore java will not do it. It will take your small number like 15 into a long but this is a waste of memory to do so if your never going to fill in the space a long uses.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Just to add to the above I assumed that the following should not have worked : float num1=4,num2=5;                                      float result=num1+num2;                                                                             but it worked not as the case of adding two short numbers as in above question

Comment: so here ,there will be a loss of data.